# Cant connect react-bootstrap to react app

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have installed react-bootstrap via:

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

my code is:

```
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counter</h1>

      <Button variant="success">Add</Button>
      <Button variant="Danger">Substract</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and buttons don't change:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to insert this line

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

in this file or in your index.js file.